# change priority (nice value) of a program permanently

Tags: system, process-priority

i am trying to change nice value to (-20) permanently for `uget-gtk` by using gnome-system-monitor. But when i end process and restart it  again, nice value by default got (0). Is there a way to set nice value to (-20) permanently for `uget-gtk`.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably want to create a simple bash script along the lines of:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo nice -n -20 uget-gtk
```

Or you could alias `uget-gtk` in your `.bashrc` file by adding:

```
alias uget-gtk='sudo nice -n -20 uget-gtk'
```

Comment: Thank you for reply,could you explain how to create bash script

Answer (score 1):

You can set priority in `/etc/security/limits.conf`:

```
user priority 0
```

or

```
@group priority 0
```