# How to speed up launching a snap app in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, snap

It takes a long time to launch a snap application for the first time or after updating it. Is there any way to speed up the process?

Comment: @karel not at all a duplicate. 1) this is specific to the snap technology 2) this is not on how to change the priority of the process once it runs, but on how to speedup the start up.

Comment: @vanadium 1. specific to snap technology does not exclude this link. 2. If it's a one-shot deal, as is written in the question to be fair because that's not the same as what's written in your comment, so now we'll have to do it both ways if we want to include both possibilities. Possible duplicate of [change priority (nice value) of a program permanently](https://askubuntu.com/questions/437607/change-priority-nice-value-of-a-program-permanently). Even so I would encourage you not to broaden this question without asking permission from the author. It would be OK to broaden it if the OP approves

Comment: @karel, this question is not about 'nicing', i.e. giving a program more priority for the processor, but about start up time of applications packaged as a snap. One of the features of Ubuntu 18.10 was indeed that snap startup times have been improved.

Comment: Can't they just backport the bug fixes of Snap to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Comment: Snap applications spent a lot of time updating mime information at first launch.  It's more I/O extensive task, could take minutes if you're using regular HDD.  I don't think user can do anything to improve this because it will require application behavior changes.

Comment: I would suggest go to snapcraft forum instead of here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [change priority (nice value) of a program permanently](https://askubuntu.com/questions/437607/change-priority-nice-value-of-a-program-permanently)